# SSRS 2008 R2 on Windows 8.1

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, windows-8.1

I installed SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 with advanced services on a Windows 8.1 environment. I selected the default configuration for the Reporting Service.

Everything seems to work, but when I try browse to the report manager I get the message

> The permissions granted to user 'LocalMachine\User' are insufficient 
>   for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)

The laptop is not part of a domain and the logged on user is the local admin. Does anyone have an idea how to overcome this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're encountering is due to UAC (user access control). Even though you're setup as an adminstrator you're account is not being treated as such unless you run IE as an Administrator.

To save having to remember this step each time, and to enable other browsers to be used and Visual Studio to deploy reports you need to setup your login as an explicit user to SSRS Server. Follow the steps below and that should do the trick.

Steps recommend using IE - other browsers can work with the following steps but not guaranteed.

- Open Internet Explorer as Administrator(Right click the IE exe and
  choose “Run as Administrator”
- Go to the “SQL Server Reporting Services” Home page (`http://localhost:port/Reports`) which will redirect to `http://localhost:port/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx`
- Click on the “Folder Settings” button.
- Click on the “New Role Assignment” button.
- Add the Group or user name: DOMAIN\USER_NAME or in this case LOCALMACHINE\USER_NAME. You'll probably want to pick Content Manager role so your account has full functionality.

Hopefully the above will do the trick.